# php user login not working anymore after I changed the way of error handling

Tags: php, error-handling

I am trying to implement a user login service on my website, registered users fill in the login form and they are transferred to member.php page, in the past I was using try and catch block and throwing exceptions, and it was working fine:

member.php

```
<?php

require_once('repository_fns.php');
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if ($username && $password) {
try {
login($username, $password);
$_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;
}
catch(Exception $e) {
do_html_header('Problem:');
echo 'You could not be logged in.
You must be logged in to view this page.';
do_html_url('login.php', 'Login');
do_html_footer();
exit;
}
}

$current_user=$_SESSION['valid_user'];

do_html_header_member();
do_page_content_member($current_user);

do_html_footer();
?>
```

the login function was like:

```
function login($username, $password) {
$conn = db_connect();
$result = $conn->query("select * from user
where username='".$username."'
and password = sha1('".$password."')");
if (!$result) {
throw new Exception('Wrong password, could not log you in.');
}

if ($result->num_rows>0) {
return true;
} else {
throw new Exception('Exception: could not log you in.');
}
```

Now I have removed those try and catch blocks, and member.php is like:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('repository_fns.php');
session_start();

if (($_POST['username']) && ($_POST['password'])) {
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  if(login($username, $password){
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $username;
  }
  else{
    do_html_header_error_page();
    do_error_message_cannot_login();
    do_html_footer();
    exit;
  }
}

$current_user=$_SESSION['valid_user'];

do_html_header_member();
do_page_content_member($current_user);

do_html_footer();

?>
```

login function:

```
function login($username, $password) {
 $conn = db_connect();
 $result = $conn->query("select * from user
 where username='".$username."'
 and password = sha1('".$password."')");
 if (!$result) {
 return false;
 }

if ($result->num_rows>0) {
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
}
```

I don't why it's not working anymore, member.php just gives me a blank page now, without any error messages. Please help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Should there be any output? If yes, a blank page usually means there is a fatal error, a missing semi colon end of the line etc. What do your error logs say? You have to be careful with error reporting, as if there is is an error in the error reporting settings, you won't get an error report. Such as your display ini settings...at a quick glance "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in your code on line 9" but this should be in your logs

Comment: @James Nothing regarding this is recorded in my error log :( , I tried to log in for two or three times and the error log remained unchanged.

Comment: @James Ohh you are right, it is on line9, a '(' is missing. Now its working, just dont know why the error log does not record this. Thank you for help!

Comment: Check out this line too: `if(login($username, $password){`. You're missing a close paren.

Comment: @phil No worries. You should get your error reporting sorted. It's a must for any dev. Perhaps move the error settings (ini display errors etc) into a separate file, and include/require it in all files. then at least you stand a chance that works and you get errors displayed. And use a better code editor with syntax highlighting - it will save you a lot of time, even just from speed of coding because it's all *visually  structured*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave you the answer in comments, but let me expand then.

You should have an error log stating such like:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in /member.php on line 9

Line 9 is:

```
  if(login($username, $password){
```

Unexpected "X" means something before it is wrong, did not complete, is not present. Because we hit something unexpected.

In this case you are missing a closing parenthesis - corrected code::

```
  if(login($username, $password)){
```

---

SIDE NOTES - to help perhaps:

If you get a good IDE or code editor, it would highlight this for you.
I use Vim, and pasted your code and the issue showed up straight away.

Another hint, while coding conventions and standards are your choice, a space before the opening brace helps see the code before it more clearly.

e.g. your *broken* code with the space added is:

```
  if(login($username, $password) {
```

You can see there is a missing `)` more easily.

Comment: I was editing codes on the online editor provided by my web hosting SP, it does not highlight syntax errors. I should get Vim right away. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: Well, Vim or one of your choice. The brief learning curve will save you hours upon hours. Especially once you start adding things like autocomplete, which autotypes variable and array names etc you have already used...